# Projection of the line segment joining the points $(3,4,5)$ and $(4,6,3)$ on the straight line obtained by joining the points $(-1,2,4)$ and $(1,0,5)$

Tags: analytic-geometry, plane-geometry

Find the projection of the line segment joining the points $(3,4,5)$ and $(4,6,3)$ on the straight line obtained by joining the points $(-1,2,4)$ and $(1,0,5)$

**My try**:

Direction ratios of the line joining the points $(3,4,5)$ and $(4,6,3)$  is $(1,2,-2)$ and direction ratios of the line   joining the points $(-1,2,4)$ and $(1,0,5)$ is $(2,-2,1)$.

To find the projection I computed the angle between the the two lines which came out as $\cos \theta =\dfrac{4}{9}$ but the answer is not coming.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The planes perpendicular to the line segment with endpoints $P=(-1,2,4)$ and 
$Q=(1,0,5)$ is of the form $2x-2y+z=c$ The plane containing $A$ is 
$\pi_1: 2x-2y+z=3$ and the plane containing $B$ is $\pi_2: 2x-2y+z = -1$

The line through the points $P=(-1,2,4)$ and $Q=(1,0,5)$ is

$\ell(t) = (2t-1,2-2t,4+t)$

We find $A' = \ell(t) \cap \pi_1$

\begin{align}
   (2t-1) + 2(2-2t) - 2(4+t) &= 3 \\
   t &= -2 \\
   A' &= \ell(-2) \\
   A' &= (-5,6,2)
\end{align}

We find $B' = \ell(t) \cap \pi_2$

\begin{align}
   (2t-1) + 2(2-2t) - 2(4+t) &= -1 \\
   t &= -1 \\
   B' &= \ell(-1) \\
   B' &= (-3,4,3)
\end{align}

The segment $\overline{A'B'}$ is the projection of the segment
$\overline{AB}$ onto the line $\overleftrightarrow{PQ}$

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake. I have fixed it.